# Copy a project from one directory to another directory - YII2 basic

Tags: css, yii2, yii2-basic-app

I have created one project in yii2-basic. In that I had done the some changes in the `bootstrap.css` in the `web/assets/dir/`.

Now I need to deploy this into another directory. I copied that project into another directory. Then I run in the browser. The changes I had done in the files are not affecting to the site. Then it refers to the another file for css.

I can't find the correct way to do this. Can anyone show me the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for changing the css you should change the original in the

```
 .\basic\vendor\bower\bootstrap\dist\css
```

then minimize it

and then in the dir web\asset you must delete the dir where is place the bootstrap (bootstrap-min.css i guess) files 
There isn't a fixed name for this asset dir,  you must find yourself the correspondent dir containing all the bootstrap part (css, js , fonts). and then remove (cancel) this dir.
Removing this dir when you accessing to the app the dir is newly recreate (normally with another asset id name).

If you don't do this when you copy a project in a new dir,  at the first access the asset  directory are newly create and the code you have change is not reached by application.

Comment: I have another query? I have to find when and where the session is expires and redirected to login page in yii2. Because I need to execute the db query when the session expires.

Comment: where process will find that session expired for current logged in user?

Comment: A session expire by time. Everey time you try an access (url) the browser check if the session  is is sill active...i suggestion to post a proper question, so the SO community can henlp you. eventually comment to me the related new link..